# How to plot the whole input from a string?

Tags: matlab, plot

Is is possible to plot all the content from a string at once without taking every part of the string and see if it is for example  sin,cos etc and plot it ? For example sinx + cosx, do I have to take all the string file, word by word ?

Comment: What do you mean by "string"? How are you plotting strings?

Comment: I want to plot the content of a string, like the content from a textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean you have a string `fncStr='sin(x)+exp(-4*x.^2)'` and for a given vector `x` you want to plot `sin(x)+exp(-4*x^2)`.

In that case you can use `eval` function

```
plot( x, eval(fncstr) );
```

You might want to use `try` and `catch` in case the string is not syntactically correct or invalid.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to do. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for interpreting that question and having the right answer.

Comment: @wakjah it's very simple for me, I just `eval( question )` and pop comes the answer ;-)

Comment: Step 1. `eval(requirementsDocument)`. Step 2. Profit!